# A groups of reviews - „assessment“ vs „evaluation“

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

I'm looking for the nuanced difference in meaning of words: „assessment“, „evaluation“ and „review“ - in the specific context of „reviewing“ various products.

As far as I understand, the main difference between „assessment“ and „evaluation“ is, that evaluation is conducted along some strict, predetermined lines - comparatively with regard to some stated standard. While assessment is more „free form“, dare I say, subjective summary without predetermined standards to compare to. Do I understand it correctly?

For context, I'm working on an application for a company that provides service of organising „testings of products“ by end-customers to companies.
And I'm looking for two right words. One for the single „review“ itself (that a single end-user provides). I'm pretty sure that calling that „a review“ is the right name, especially since it already seems as a deep-rooted meaning of the word.

The second word is more puzzling though... I have no idea how to call a „group“ of such reviews - an „organised effort to collect reviews of a product“. This „campaign“ is conducted within a certain time period and only with selected testers (end-customers). However since „campaign“ is evoking quite a different meanings to me, it doesn't seems most appropriate. Since there are no strict, predetermined standards, calling it a „product evaluation“ doesn't seem right to me either. Could such a „campaign“ be called „a product assessment“?
A „product assessment“ that comprises of multiple individual „product reviews“? How would you call such an effort/campaign?

Comment: You may use "testing of products" or "tests of products" but not "testings of products". Testing does not take a plural. Nor does training nor cannon.  As for *group of* tests, I would say a *series* of tests. The series you can describe and modify as you like.

Answer (score 1):

"Review analysis" is what I'd suggest for a result of reviewing user reviews.

As to the difference between assessment and evaluation, I don't think there is  any. To me, the words mean exactly the same thing and choosing one over the other is a matter of tradition. For example, I think that "project evaluation" is the usual expression for what an organization does after a project is completed and they want to figure out how it went. On the other hand, "risk assessment" is a standard term for judging whether you should do something or not. From these two examples, it seems like "evaluation" means looking at something in retrospect while "assessment" is applied to something that is coming in the future but I don't think this is hundred percent true. It will definitely vary depending on the context.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Although I'm not sure I'm any more wise. Before I asked here, I tried to research the topic - for instance: https://keydifferences.com/difference-between-assessment-and-evaluation.html
However the more I read about it, the more and more confusing it seems 

Comment: Assessment is often used in education in the UK to mean any way of rating student performance (exam, coursework, thesis, etc) so it's just as formal and criteria-based. I wonder if there's a difference in the US.

Comment: @StuartF, but then, in education-related contexts, *assessment* is sometimes also used for what education bureaucrats do in what they describe as their scrutiny of how well courses or educational programmes accomplish their purposes.

Answer (score 1):

So far as English language and usage, outside the jargon of specific fields is concerned, *assessment* and *evaluation* are largely interchangeable, as can be confirmed by consulting general-purpose dictionaries that define them in terms of each other.

It is possible that, in the jargon of a particular field, or just of a particular organisation, the two terms are used with different meanings, or that, even if their meaning is essentially the same, it is customary to confine the use of each of them to a particular context. The questions about such a highly localised usage are, however, outside the scope of this site; one is likely to get better answers to them by consulting those who work in the relevant field or the relevant organisation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for an answer to a particular question or evidence supporting a hypothesis "**systematic review**" and "**meta-analysis**" would have served your purpose. These terms are primarily used in the medical field.

You can possibly use "[scoping review](https://guides.temple.edu/c.php?g=78618&p=4156607)" or "[mapping review](https://guides.temple.edu/c.php?g=78618&p=5094330)"

[Systematic review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systematic_review) and [Meta-analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-analysis) wikipedia links.

If you do not want to use these too technical terms, you may choose to use some words of the same ilk in combination, e.g. scrutiny of assessments, audit of assessments, scrutiny of evaluations etc.